# How do I copy a directory every time I build the project?

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to copy the `res` directory into the build directory but it only happens when I reload the CMake file and build the project. Here's the code I'm using to achieve this:

```
add_custom_command(
        TARGET project PRE_BUILD
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/res/ $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:project>/res/
)
```

I've tried using the `file` command to copy the directory, but that method also has this issue. Is there a way to copy a directory every time I build the project?

Comment: It is operating system specific. On Linux, use the [cp(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html) command, or toolkits like [POCO](https://pocoproject.org/) or [Qt](https://qt.io/)

Comment: you are missing the OUTPUT parameter. Then you define a custom target which depends on the output file

Comment: The way to do something every time you build the project is `add_custom_target`. Not sure why do you use `add_custom_command`.